# Menu overlapping with Logo

Tags: css, wordpress

I am building a website with wordpress.
The url is [here](http://rosaegg.at/S/)

My problem is that the menu is overlapping with the logo until the screen size is 1300px ... can i force the mobile / burger menu to appear until it has 1300px or is there any other solution for this?

Comment: You can use a css media query for that.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: As ngearing mentioned, you can use media queries to change the layout based on the screen size. Here's an example of the most common media query sizes: https://scotch.io/tutorials/default-sizes-for-twitter-bootstraps-media-queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1300px) {

    .main_menu {
        display: none !important;
    }

    .mobile_menu_button {
        display: table !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for... I played around with the @media only screen thing but found no solution! Thank you so much

Comment: My only problem is now that the mobile menu won`t open... it is only displaying the button

Comment: Could you try adding the following to the media query:

    nav.mobile_menu { display: block }

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of using media queries to drop you navigation below your logo if the screen width is above 1300px, and below 1500px (since it looks fine on wide screens).

```
@media (min-width: 1300px) and (max-width: 1500px) {
    header .header_inner_left {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0;
    }
}
```

You'll have to add this to your stylesheet and play around with the dimensions of your query, but this should solve the collision issue. You can also use media queries (like your theme is doing when it turns the navigation into a hamburger stack navigation) by switching styles in your stylesheet based on the screen size. There are more than one styles that are being modified to create a functional mobile navigation, so this route may be the easiest if you want to avoid needling through the core theme code.

Hope that helps! Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I solved this now with the mobile menu but I will play around a little bit and keep this in my mind